# Select a field with multiple where clause

Tags: where-clause

I need to select a field with multiple where clause. The below query causes a syntax error.

```
String selectquery="SELECT" +KEY_EXPAMT+ "FROM" +TABLE_EXP+ "WHERE" 

+KEY_EXPCAT+ "='" +String.valueOf(cat)+ "'AND " +KEY_EXPMONTH+ "='" 

+String.valueOf(month)+ "' AND " +KEY_EXPYEAR+ "='" +String.valueOf(year)+ "' 

AND " +KEY_EXPFROM+ "='" +String.valueOf(from)+"'";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, new String[]{cat, month,year,from});
```

logcat:

> 03-20 15:01:36.606  19106-19125/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
>   03-20 15:01:36.623  19106-19106/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
>   03-20 15:01:36.680  19106-19125/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem I/Adreno-EGL﹕ : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1__release_AU ()
>       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
>       Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
>       Local Branch:
>       Remote Branch: quic/l_LNX.LA.3.6
>       Local Patches: NONE
>       Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107 + cb93e16 + f50fe49 + d7c18e6 + 5b9a565 + 0f3a25d + 607156e + 75511aa + e4d16c0 + 686f3eb + 211a271 + dd281ee +  NOTHING
>   03-20 15:01:36.683  19106-19125/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   03-20 15:01:36.762  19106-19125/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>   03-20 15:01:48.482  19106-19106/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   03-20 15:01:48.494  19106-19125/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution
>   03-20 15:01:48.507  19106-19125/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb862fc90 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
>   03-20 15:02:13.932  19106-19106/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "SELECTexpenseamountFROMexpenseWHEREexpensecategory": syntax error
>   03-20 15:02:13.946  19106-19106/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>   03-20 15:02:13.962  19106-19106/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem, PID: 19106
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECTexpenseamountFROMexpenseWHEREexpensecategory": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECTexpenseamountFROMexpenseWHEREexpensecategory='food'AND expensemonth='march' AND expenseyear='2015' AND expensefrom='InBank'
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
>               at com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem.SqlLiteDb.updateExpense(SqlLiteDb.java:122)
>               at com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem.ExpensingAmountActivity$4$1.onClick(ExpensingAmountActivity.java:145)
>               at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:160)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>   03-20 15:02:15.674  19106-19106/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19106 SIG: 9
>   03-20 15:02:16.502  20366-20387/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
>   03-20 15:02:16.518  20366-20366/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
>   03-20 15:02:16.576  20366-20387/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem I/Adreno-EGL﹕ : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1__release_AU ()
>       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
>       Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
>       Local Branch:
>       Remote Branch: quic/l_LNX.LA.3.6
>       Local Patches: NONE
>       Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107 + cb93e16 + f50fe49 + d7c18e6 + 5b9a565 + 0f3a25d + 607156e + 75511aa + e4d16c0 + 686f3eb + 211a271 + dd281ee +  NOTHING
>   03-20 15:02:16.578  20366-20387/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   03-20 15:02:16.609  20366-20387/com.expense.javed.expensetrackingsystem D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: Show the error message. Use prepared statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. Your code is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack. You should really use prepared statements with ? placeholders for the values, and then set the values later. Or, at a minimum, you should escape the strings properly. To learn about SQL injection, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

However, as for your error, I think this says it all:

> "SELECTexpenseamountFROMexpenseWHEREexpensecategory='food'AND expensemonth='march' AND expenseyear='2015' AND expensefrom='InBank'"

You are missing spaces in your query.